# How to calculate sound card clock drift?

Tags: audio, soundcard, drift, echo-cancellation

I'm calculating sound card drift for reasons of acoustic echo cancellation. My algorithm is:

```
drift = samples_played - sampled_recorded
```

Where *samples_played* is incremented by 1 when a 320, 640 or 1920 byte audio frame is sent to the playback device and where *samples_recorded* is incremented by 1 when a 320, 640 or 1920 byte audio frame has been output by the capture device.

A description of what I am trying to accomplish is provided by WebRTC as follows:

**WebRtc_Word16 skew  Difference between number of samples played and recorded at the soundcard (for clock skew compensation).**

My question is two-part:

1. Is the algorithm correct?
2. Is the increment correct?

Comment: Why are you using those byte sizes?  You would need an awful lot of audio data for a single sample to be 320 bytes.  Can you expand a bit more on what you are trying to measure?  You want to know the full latency for playback and record?  Or are you measuring clock drift?

Comment: 320, 640 and 1920 are common frame sizes for VoIP.

Comment: Ah, then your method is wrong.  You will find many more than one sample per frame.  Since clock drift isn't very fast (usually), you will need to find a way to get down to the sample level, if possible.

Comment: The sample sizes are 160, 320 and 960 respectively (frame size in bytes / sizeof(int16_t)).

Comment: Also, I've added more detail to the question.